# How do I globally declare jQuery inside a Vue-CLI 3 project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have seen a lot of questions about this on SO and elsewhere, but so far I had no luck.

For a bit of context, I built a SPA website on a Vue project I created with an "old" command. I don't remember which one but it looked like the following:

`vue init webpack <my project>`

I recently realized that Vue-CLI 3 would be way easier for me to maintain, keep updated and improve for various contextual reasons, so I installed `@vue/cli`, created a new project and started to copy/paste files from my old project to the new one.

The old project had a `build` directory with various webpack config files in it, and I needed jQuery set globally for a package I wanted to use, so I added the following to the "base" config of Webpack.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}),
```

However, with the new project, all I have now as config file is `babel.config.js` and `vue.config.js` at the project's root, there are no `build` nor `config` directory.

I tried to set jQuery globally with the following lines inside my `main.js` file:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery
```

But everytime I reload my page, I get the following message:

> > jQuery is not defined

So, so far, I use the CDN version of jQuery but I don't feel at ease with this solution.

How should I proceed with a Vue-CLI 3 project?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't! The point of a modern templating engine like Vue is so you don't use a legacy library like jQuery. Just don't!

Comment: The thing is, I can't find or make a vanilla js package work in a Vue context..

Comment: You should just use `import jquery from jquery` in the beginning of each .js/.vue you need it in, and then jquery("#id").whatever)`

Comment: you perhaps could add it to the `Vue()` and access it via `this.$jquery` inside of `.vue` files, haven't tried it thou.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vue plugins. This allows you to add new property to every single component.

In `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

Vue.use({
  install (V) {
    V.$jQuery = V.prototype.$jQuery = jQuery
  }
})
```

Then you can use jQuery everywhere in component.

In `MyComponent.vue`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$jQuery('h1').text('Hello World')
    Vue.$jQuery('h1').text('Hello World')
  }
}
```

Even another js file.

In `util.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.$jQuery('h1').text('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go on public/index.html and add the script tag to the body with the route to your jquery file or cdn.
If you put it in a jquery folder in public it would look like:

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am not sure if that's exactly what you want but it would make it available globally across your project.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Jquery plugins, you should do this in your main.js:

```
/*
* If using Jquery plugins they will expect to be available in the global namespace, 
* which isn’t the case when you import/require it. So manually assign jquery to 
* window. Use require instead of import because the imports are hoisted to the
* top of a file by the compiler, which would break VueJS code.
*/
const $ = require('jquery')
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
```